# How to force R to make a copy of scalar at a separate memory location

Tags: r, memory, copy, scalar

When we assign the value of a variable to another variable in R, they would share the same memory location before they have different values. This saves the memory but sometime can cause trouble. For example, if I assign the value of variable a0 to variable b0 and then pass both a0 and b0 to an Rcpp function by reference, changing the value of a0 in the function would cause undesired change of b0. I need to make extra copy of b0 before the change of a0 to hold the value.

To avoid the trouble described above, using as.numeric() (for vectors) and data.frame() for (dataframes) to assign value of one variable to another would force R to make a copy at a separate memory location. However, this does not work for length 1 vector (scalar).

```
a0=1:3
b0=a0
c0=as.numeric(a0)
tracemem(a0) == tracemem(b0)#TRUE
tracemem(a0) == tracemem(c0)#FALSE

a0=4
b0=a0
c0=as.numeric(a0)
tracemem(a0) == tracemem(b0)#TRUE
tracemem(a0) == tracemem(c0)#TRUE
```

I think there are some work-around like making an extra copy to hold the value or do a simple plus and minus change to the scalar to make the values different. But I am wondering how people usually deal with this problem.

Comment: So this is a problem because you want to modify the value by reference in your RCpp code? And you specifically want to do this for a scalar value? Is this for some kind of optimization?

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I am using Rcpp function which would update variable a0 and compare to its old version b0 in an iteration and if a0 got improved the value of a0 would be assigned to b0 and move forward to next iteration. If a0 and b0 use the same memory location, updating a0 in Rcpp function would also change the value of b0. Updating a0 is computational intensive so I use Rcpp to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Just find that as.numeric(a0)[1] would create a copy at different memory location

```
a0=4
b0=as.numeric(a0)
c0=as.numeric(a0)[1]
tracemem(a0) == tracemem(b0)#TRUE
tracemem(a0) == tracemem(c0)#FALSE
```